# Add revisions list to tag wiki

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, revisions-list, tag-wiki

So I took a look at this new [Tag Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=sql-server&sort=info&pagesize=50) thing.

I can "edit wiki" on tags where I have high enough score, but there is no UI to show revision history like with questions and answers.

I think it would be a nice thing to have.

Comment: [­](https://meta.stackexchange.com)Yeah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's got some quirks, but at least it is [status-completed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/62887/revisions) now.

Answer (score 8):

Agreed!

From my question that was pointed out to be a dupe:

> I think we need a revision history along with the editor for the wiki pages.
>
> Right now, I could swoop in, delete the content of the [**`[C#]`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=c%23&sort=info&pagesize=30) page and leave. And no one (maybe mods) will be able to see who did it.

Comment: Heh, I wouldn't have guessed that you had 100 C# votes -- but it turns out I have 88, and I barely know C#.

Comment: @mmy I use C# at work, so I know it about as well as Java.  I just prefer Java.