# Editing a tag-wiki should show in your activity log

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, tag-wiki

The activity tag in a users profile should include a log of tag-wiki editing.

Probably goes with or comes after [Tag Wiki - visible edit history / rollback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57997/tag-wiki-visible-edit-history-rollback).

Comment: I think there was a backpedalling somewhere. I'm certain that there used to be tag wiki activity in the activity summary, [because they're the same post type that the FAQ is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66342/is-the-faq-revision-history-meant-to-be-fully-public "And I'm pretty sure I didn't write that question until after tag wikis were added to revision history, anyway"). But, right now, neither is visible (while, strangely, election comments *are* recorded). I wonder why that was changed.

Comment: I actually consider this a bug

Comment: @waffles: I'm with you, but this was first posted when the tag wiki system was still young. So I didn't want to complain too soon.

Answer (score 3):

You should now see wiki creation / revisions in the user activity.