# Have Code Golf questions been implicitly disallowed on StackOverflow, now that migration to PSE is possible?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, migration, code-golf

Refer to Exhibit A:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/30273/codegolf-find-the-unique-paths

This question was migrated to [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) from StackOverflow.  Note that there seems to be some confusion in the comments below the question about what should be the appropriate home for Code Golf questions.

I suspect that this particular question was migrated, at least in part, not because it is Code Golf, but because it was ultimately uninteresting to the SO community.  But if that's the case, it probably should have been closed as NARQ, rather than "pawned off" on PSE.

Can we have some community clarification about this?

Comment: I still find the idea that Programmers is the destination fro code golf questions really strange. Jeff may have put it in the p.se FAQ, but it does not make any kind of sense to me.

Comment: @dmckee - couldn't agree more.  Code golf is way too code specific for PSE.  I could be wrong but the only code golf question to date was one migrated from SO.

Answer (score 11):

After some further thought, **I don't think Code Golf questions belong on p.se** since they are so code-focused and the primary (though by no means final) rule of thumb for whether something belongs on SO or p.se is "does it contain code, and is the question primarily about code?"

So, I removed the section on the Programmers Stack Exchange FAQ which allowed Code Golf there. **Code Golf questions should stay on Stack Overflow for now** (and must be flagged for moderator attention to get the cwiki flag set on them), until such time as the [Area 51 Code Golf](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4570/code-golf-programming-puzzles) proposal gets traction.

Comment: It's important to have a clear definition. I personally can't see Code Golf on PSE. Code is a SO beast or another site.

Comment: Can the explicit mention of Code Golf questions be removed from the [Programmers.SE FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq)? That was added unilaterally with no input from a community that [does not want them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67780/why-is-code-golf-now-the-domain-of-programmers-se).

Comment: as a long time follower of CG questions, I think they have utility on the Stack Overflow site because they teach you about code. Have you seen some of those Perl solutions? They don't fit nearly as well on Stack Exchange because they aren't really about the softer side of software engineering. I believe they belong on Stack Overflow, and if the `code-golf` tag automatically made them CW, then I'd be ok with it (providing the tag could only be used by a moderator or 20K'r, and the votes were retroactively removed).

Comment: just to let you know -- fragmentation is going to kill SO.

Comment: @Popular Demand: Well, Robert's request was, "Can we have some community clarification about this?" Rejected implies that Robert had a request which was then denied.