# Disappeared question (and related answers)

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions, policy, code-golf

I was looking for a code golf question (first question I answered on SO) and I noticed it had disappeared from "answers" in my profile. I searched for it, with no results, then I found it by looking at the badge I got for that answer, but I got this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437/what-is-your-solution-to-the-fizzbuzz-problem/2981194#2981194

I think this is strange because it had a zillion answers (many were instructive answers, others good examples of a code-golfer's wet dreams, others both) and it was there for years. So I doubt it was removed for moderation or by the author.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, here's what 10k rep users and up can see:

[image]

SO is growing out of this kind of question--<strike>programmers.SE is the more appropriate site for code golf questions now.</strike> Code golf isn't on-topic for Programmers.SE anymore - [we have a dedicated site.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

As for Jeff deleting it, I can't see anything in the history that suggests any of the obvious reasons for such an action.  Perhaps he'll pop in with some info.

---

As per comments on this answer, I'm re-opening the question as wiki.  Until next week, at which point JA will come up with a different solution for code golf questions.

Comment: Actually Code Golf was also removed from Programmers scope. They don't have a home at the moment as far as I am aware.

Comment: You need to keep with the times, Will! [Jeff Atwood](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73332/have-code-golf-questions-been-implicitly-disallowed-on-stackoverflow-now-that-mi) declared that Code Golf is better on Stack Overflow, and inappropriate for Programmers. Note that this deletion happened *before* said announcement, though.

Comment: @Diago damn Programmers annoys the hell outta me.  I'm thinking of not migrating there anymore, as whatever I think PSE is about is never correct.

Comment: thanks everybody! things are (just a lil bit) clearer now :-) I'm a newbie, but as far as I understand, wouldnt migrating "misplaced" question be better than deleting them?

Comment: @Mattia If human judgement wasn't required, it would all be handled automatically.  Unfortunately it is, which means decisions are always vulnerable to the failings of human judgement.

Comment: @Will Nice one!

Answer (score 4):

This is not Code Golf. Code Golf is "provide the smallest solution".

This question is just "provide any solution in any language, the more LOLZ the better".

In short, *a waste of time*.

I'm not sure where it belongs, but not any site in our network.