# I have a code golf question to ask, but I can't make it a community wiki question

Tags: support, community-wiki, code-golf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should be done about [code-golf] on Stack Overflow in light of the new CW policy?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67686/what-should-be-done-about-code-golf-on-stack-overflow-in-light-of-the-new-cw-po)

I'd like to ask an original code golf question. So I typed it up, eager to see what kind of regex nonsense the perl hackers would spew at it and someone's ludicrous response in brain***k, but when it was time to hit submit, there was no Community Wiki question button to press.

Now, I understand the rationale behind a CW question. I used to not, but I've spent some time on SO and I know how things work. That said, I'm not sure how to ask my code golf question without being attacked by the SO police since there's no CW.

What can I do about this?

Comment: As you have discovered, CW has been [disabled for new questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67039/what-can-we-do-to-make-community-wiki-better/67192#67192). There's a question out there about [what happens to code golf now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67686/what-should-be-done-about-code-golf-on-stack-overflow-in-light-of-the-new-cw-po) that may interest you.

Comment: Thanks, you should post this as an answer so I can upvote and accept it. I think I'll just ask the question anyway, flag it for CW, and see what happens.

Comment: thanks, but I think this is basically a dupe of that second link, so I don't want any rep for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a lot of negative things happening with questions that started out community wiki, so we decided it is better to not allow that to be a user controllable option.

For now, if you need a question to be community wiki, flag it for moderator attention.