# How do I migrate Stackoverflow questions that belong on other StackExchange sites?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, migration

Is there any plan in the future to migrate subjective questions to Programmers SE or will those questions remain on Stackoverflow as historical questions?

In addition, if there will be a plan to migrate questions, will other related questions eventually be migrated?

For example [Code Golf & Programming Puzzles](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4570/code-golf-programming-puzzles) is the commitment phase. If it successfully goes into beta, will stackoverflow questions tagged with *Code Golf* be transfered over?

Comment: If you are interested in the fate of [code-golf] questions in particular see [What should be done about code-golf on Stack Overflow in light of the new CW policy?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67686/2509).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can suggest questions to be migrated to Programmers SE [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71731/programmers-is-about-to-go-live-which-questions-should-we-migrate).

Although I don't think any questions will be migrated to a beta site, they might if it makes it to the live stage.