# Is this a code golf question, and what should be done about it?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, code-golf

I came across https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274313/why-is-my-game-of-life-code-so-verbose/6274338#6274338 today, and I'm wondering if it should be moved to the [Code Golf SE beta](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/). Does the fact that it'd be on-topic for SE mean it must be migrated away from Stack Overflow?

Other questions about code golf have been asked, but that was before the Code Golf SE was set up.

Comment: I've voted to close that question as off topic.

Comment: I think we decided not to move existing Stack Overflow code golfs, but that we could (not must) migrate *new* questions that are (a) off topic on SO and (b) would be on-topic on CodeGolf. Only I can't find a reference for that, just now.

Comment: From after the new CW policy but before CG.SE started: [What should be done about code-golf on Stack Overflow in light of the new CW policy?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67686/2509).

Comment: Code Golf questions should go to Code Golf, when it emerges from beta. Your example is more of a "help me with this code" request that happens to be a Code Golf. Also, note that [some of CG.SE's statistics are worrying;](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4570/code-golf-programming-puzzles) there's no guarantee that it will emerge from beta without being discontinued.

Answer (score 6):

How about [codereview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead? This is clearly a rewrite request (or rather, asking for hints for a rewrite).

The fact that this is a code golf is rather incidental.

Comment: I'd migrate right now, as the OP is asking to improve working code...

Comment: @Won't Let me guess: … but you won’t? ;-)

Comment: Not right now.  Waiting to see what happens here.

Comment: on the contrary, on Stack Overflow he Will♦ http://stackoverflow.com/users/1228/will

Comment: @DanielDiPaolo I was already afraid that my cheapo joke would be lost.

Answer (score 2):

I'm actually going to suggest that in it's current form that is *not* a good question for CodeGolf.SE, and it doesn't really pose a puzzle for other to participate it, and the only other category of question we are accepting right now is *"Tips on golfing in [language]"*.

The poster can be directed to our question on [golfing tips in ruby](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/363/tips-for-golfing-in-ruby) which may help.

We *don't* have a Game of Life golf on the site right now, but there was [a quite successful one on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499538/code-golf-conways-game-of-life), where the poster my find some instructive examples as well.