# This tag has no tag wiki, but wait... (wiki not found by preview)

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tag-wiki

It appears that [delphi] has no tag wiki. Since I have invested some time into it, I know there once was one.

[image]

I just read about the [new tag wiki revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57997/tag-wiki-visible-edit-history-rollback) and clicked through to see whether the tag wiki was still available in a revision. But what did I find?

[image]

Everything was still there.
It seems that the recognition algorithm does not find the wiki text any more after the change was made to revisions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this is by-design.

The tag wikis are upgraded on the fly, you can see the full list of wikis that were upgraded here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/tag-wikis

First time anyone visits the a wiki that was not upgraded to the new "post" format (which gives you the nice history and so on) it will upgrade the wiki.

Its a one time operation so its not really worth fixing.

Answer (score 0):

This has since been fixed - maybe just a matter of releases. But now it looks as it should again:
[image]