# Odd, linkless revisions appearing in my activity list

Tags: bug, status-completed, recent-activity, revisions-list, tag-wiki

On [my Stack Overflow activity page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/151292?tab=activity#tab-top), there are seven "revised" entries that don't link to any post:

[image]

Thank you, Jon B, for the beautiful freehand circles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a side affect of Post Type wiki. I will fix up the links tomorrow so it links to the tag wiki :)

**EDIT** fixed

Comment: I was guessing this (and was writing an answer, too!), since the timestamp so closely corresponded to your implementing the new post type. But what determines whether these get recorded in your activity? I just did some [revisions on Gaming](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/6638/revisions), and I haven't seen [any effect yet](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/85?tab=activity#tab-top).

Comment: Okay... I just got one of 5 revisions added to my revision history. Maybe it only records significantly body edits...

Comment: Hooray!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me in light of the [new tag wiki revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57997/tag-wiki-visible-edit-history-rollback). When I wanted to look at a tag wiki as the first user after the revision feature had been included, the tag wiki migrated to the new structure. It looks as if for all revisions there is a recent activity entry generated when the tag wiki is ported.

Look at [this entry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62898/this-tag-has-no-tag-wiki-but-wait-wiki-not-found-by-preview) as well, especially waffles answer.