# Cannot roll back invalid tag wiki edit

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-wiki, rollbacks

[This suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2651855) was just approved by three (of 5) voters, which saddens me greatly. Not only is it poorly formatted (abuse of code formatting, inappropriate spacing between letters, lack of punctuation), it is also not a good description of the tag. Like the other person who voted to reject wrote, it tries to cram mostly-unrelated information about Symphony into a generic tag.

Oh well, I'll just roll it back. Great, I know how to do that…except I don't.

First, I tried to go to the [tag wiki edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18043957/revisions), but the initial Community-created revision does not have the expected "rollback" link.

Then, I tried to manually roll back by [editing the wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/33718) and removing the text. But I can't do that—the system stomps on my hand and says that the "wiki excerpt is missing". Yes, I know that. That's the point.

Finally, I tried searching Meta, but all I found was [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62938/can-we-have-a-method-to-revert-the-tag-wiki-excerpt-to-its-original-state), which indicates that the problem was already solved by adding the Community revision, which is precisely the one I was trying to roll back to.

**I have plenty of rep to edit tag wikis, but yet I don't see the "rollback" link for this wiki or any others. What gives?** Shouldn't users with full edit privileges also be able to roll back invalid edits?

Comment: Hmmm, the rollback link shows up for me. Let's click it and see what happens. That always leads to good things, right?

Comment: You probably can't roll back the first revision of a post, since there's nothing to roll back _to_; deleting this probably takes a DB admin. Edit: Unless I'm wrong, of course.

Comment: @Emrakul Yes, you can. That's what the Community-created revision is for. It works on all other posts, it should work on tag wikis too. *Deleting* it would require a database edit, but I don't care if it's in the history.

Comment: @animuson Weird, it works fine for you. Surely rolling back tag wikis is not a moderator-only feature? I should see a "rollback" link, right?

Comment: @Cody Huh. You can roll back a post to... nothing? That's interesting...

Comment: @CodyGray: I wouldn't think so. Are there still no rollback links with the added revision?

Comment: Nope. Actually, I see no rollback links for *any* tag wikis.

Comment: Gaaaa! I'm often guilty of typoing "its" with a gratuitous apostrophe, but doing so TWICE in something that's supposed to stand as a reference and using a backtick operator instead of an apostrophe is a whole special level of KILL_IT_WITH_FIRE.

Comment: @animuson Any thoughts on if this will be implemented?  It makes trying to remove copied content harder without a rollback link.

Comment: **To close voters**: the issue was *fixed*, not *no longer reproducible*. That close reason is intended for *ephemeral* issues that resolve themselves after a short while, not for actual bugs that are later marked completed. The [tag:status-completed] tag is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed.

The "can edit" logic for displaying the UI was only showing it for moderators on tag wikis; now "edit" and "rollback" will both show up for trusted users.

There was also a bug in the server side validation, which no one would ever hit because of the UI, where non-mod trusted users could only rollback posts *if* they also were blocked from posting suggested edits.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯