# Why can't we erase actively-harmful usage guidance/wiki excerpts?

Tags: feature-request, edits, tag-wiki-excerpt

If you try to delete a useless usage guidance excerpt, you can't save the edit, because you get an error message that "Wiki Excerpt is missing." No kidding. That's the whole point!

Why is the excerpt absolutely required once it is ever populated, even for tags that are reasonably self-descriptive? It's nice to want to have guidance for every tag, but often it's far more practical to just rely on the tag name, and stopping an editor in their tracks can be harmful if they're just trying to help by clearing away guidance that's outright counterproductive. For example, [which](/questions/tagged/which) on ELL: "For questions that use the word 'which'." How about we not include [Should I put a dash in this sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11350/should-i-put-a-dash-in-this-sentence) in that, OK? In cases like this, it would be far better to have nothing at all than to have that bit of drivel.

Even [20kers can't get around this limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191872/cannot-roll-back-invalid-tag-wiki-edit). Please allow editor discretion, rather than enforcing an inconsistently and unrealistically high standard for fixes to terrible excerpts.

Comment: Well, same goes for posts: you can't just totally remove a post by editing.

Comment: Maybe a HTML comment can be used as workaround? `<!-- excerpt removed by reasons -->` -I'm not seeing it listed on the possible duplicate...

Comment: @brasofilo: It's an excerpt, so no. No markup or markdown or anything.

Comment: oh... true that... forgot about it...

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Sure enough. At least this will now point those searching for that infuriating error message in the right place.